# Can someone please explain step by step what this 'by' and 'if' statements in SAS data step is doing?

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and trying to understand what is happening in the below code

```
data def;
     set abc;
      by id;
     if last.id;
run;
```

I understand that `by` is used for sorting by `id` column, but what is `if last.id` doing?

Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data def;
```

*Create a data set named `DEF` (which will be stored in the default library `WORK`)*;

```
    set abc;
```

*get your input from dataset `ABC` (which sas will look for in the default library `WORK`) This will automatically generate a loop over the observations (1)*;

```
    by id;
```

*add temporary variables (2) `first.id` and `last.id` to indicate if this is the first/last observation with that `id` (3)*;

```
    if last.id;
```

*All statements below, as well as the implicit `output;` statement, will only apply to the last observation of each `id`. It is equivalent to `if not last.id then delete;`.*;

```
run;
```

*Compile the above and run*;

(1) In a SAS data step, you should (almost) never write something like

```
read file;
while not eof;
    do some stuf;
    read file;
end;
```

This is automated by the `set` and `merge` statements.

(2) Temporary variables exist in the "program vector" (i.e. are in scope in the data set), but are not written to the output data set.

(3) The word **observation** in SAS jargon is the same as **row** in database jargon. The difference with a record is, that the sas table, like a database, knows its own structure. 
Without that, the `by` statement and many other facilities of the language could not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
if last.id;
```

is a special form of `if` different than other coding languages, notice there is no `THEN` clause.  The form is known as a ***subsetting if***.  The DATA step flow of control beyond that `if` only occurs when *test-expression* is true.

In your code the *test-expression* is `last.id`.

`last.<variable>` (and corresponding `first.<variable>`) are two automatic temporary variables created for each `BY` variable and indicate if the current row is at a group edge row; either the first or last row of a by-group level.

You can infer information about where the current observation is within the group

```
FIRST.  LAST.   where
  1             at first in group
  0             not at first in group
          1     at last in group
          0     not at last in group
  1       0     group has >= 2 rows and currently at first in group
  0       0     group has >= 3 rows and currently in the middle part
  0       1     group has >= 2 rows and currently at last in group
  1       1     group has only 1 row
```

You do need to understand the underlying premises of the implicit loop fundamental to `DATA/SET` processing:

- A good starter is SUGI 30 paper ["A Hands-On Introduction to SAS® DATA Step Programming"](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi30/134-30.pdf)
  Debbie Buck, D. B. & P. Associates, Houston, TX".
- Ian Whitlock's papers are some of the best.  Try his SUGI 31 ["How to Think Through the SAS® DATA Step
  "](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi31/246-31.pdf)